Injective map from a compact Hausdorff domain
Let $f:X\to Y$ be an injective continuous map where $X$ is compact and Hausdorff. Is then $f$ a homeomorphism onto its image?
I tried to apply that a continuous bijection from a compact to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism onto its image but for this I need $f(X)$ to be Hausdorff which fails in general.

No: take $X={0,1}$ with the discrete topology, $Y=X$ with the indiscrete topology and $f(x)=x$. More generally, whenever you have a compact topology on $(X,\tau)$ and a strictly coarser topology $(Y,\rho)=(X,\rho)$ you automatically have that the latter is compact and $x\mapsto x$ is continuous $X\to Y$ and not closed.

In a manner of speaking, the situation where $X$ is compact Hausdorff, $Y$ is a coarser topology on $X$ and $f(x)=x$ essentially describes the counterexamples to your claim.

Thanks so far. Does the claim hold in metric spaces?

You're already aware of the fact that it's true when $Y$ is Hausdorff (for the record, even if $X$ T2 is not given) and my counterexample has $X$ metrizable.

Let $g$ be the inverse of $f:X\to f(X)$ and $C$ be closed in $X$. Then $g^{-1}(C)=f(C)$ is closed in $f(X)$ because $C$ is compact as a closed set in compact metric $X$, $f(C)$ is again compact and thus closed. What am I missing?

$f(C)$ may not be closed.

It is as a compact subset of the metric subspace $f(X)$

Then I've already discussed that.
